# Dapper.Rainbow with existing database schema

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-rainbow

I am trying out Dapper. I like what I have seen so far. In order to do simple CRUD, I use Dapper.rainbow. It works very well. However, it works only if the table has identity column with name *Id*. It makes sense to have db like that but I can not ask for column name change in database just to use Dapper. To be more clear, I am working with database like Northwind Db. It has tablename repeated in Id column everywhere.

In order to handle this,I changed the Dapper.Rainbow code as below:

```
   public T Get(TId id,string idColumnName="Id")
        {
            return database.Query<T>("select * from " + TableName + " where               "+idColumnName+" = @id", new { id }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Is there a better way to handle this such as Column mapping /annotations or something completely different?

I have read questions like these

[Manually Map column names with class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902674/manually-map-column-names-with-class-properties)

[Dapper.Rainbow VS Dapper.Contrib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030285/dapper-rainbow-vs-dapper-contrib)

( I came across similar little problem with Dapper.Contrib, I will ask it separately).

**Update** - Not sure if the answers are applicable to my Dapper.Rainbow problem here (Atleast, I don't see how).

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Looks like a pretty viable approach to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The existing Dapper extensions did not fit my ideal pattern. I wanted simple CRUD operations with smart defaults without anything extra. I also wanted to have models with additional properties that did not directly map to the database. For example - a FullName property that combines FirstName and LastName in its getter - and not add FullName to the Insert and Update statements.

I wanted the primary key column to be Id in most cases but allow overriding with an attribute.

Finally, I wanted the table name to match the class name by default but allow overriding with an attribute.

I ended up writing my own extension to Dapper that solves these issues. Its on Github and Nuget. Hopefully it will be helpful to you.

https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD

Comment: Is there nuget package for this?

Comment: The T4 has a package too. https://nuget.org/packages/Dapper.SimpleCRUD.ModelGenerator/

Comment: +1 Fantastic! It works! I started writing a sample DAL layer based on Rainbow (https://github.com/YogirajA/Dapper.DAL) and bumped on to this issue. I was also using t4 template to generate pocos from DB but your template is much better. Now, I will use SimpleCrud for my DAL application and projects. Thanks very much!

Comment: @ericdc Awesome work!  You wouldn't have by chance a T4 generator for MySQL, would you?

Comment: @ericdc, is it possible for you to add option to allow insert without the second sql statement which return the @@identity? This is to support MS Access/Jet. Thank you.