# Add/Insert style of petapoco vs dapper

Tags: dapper, petapoco

I am **delighted** by this:

// Insert a record with peta poco

```
var a = new Article();
a.title="My new article";
a.content="PetaPoco was here";
a.date_created=DateTime.UtcNow;
db.Insert(a);
```

I am **distracted** by this:

// Insert a record with dapper

```
var a = new Article();
a.title="My new article";
a.content="PetaPoco was here";
a.date_created=DateTime.UtcNow;
string articleQuery= "INSERT INTO Article VALUES (@Title, @Content, @Date)";        
connection.Execute(articleQuery, new { Title = a.Title, Content = a.Content, Date = a.Date });
```

I am new to dapper and peta poco. It might be that there is more in dapper that I have not found but I really do not like the way I have to do an insert. Peta poco seems to do it very ormish.

Can dapper do this somehow too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [dapper extensions](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions) for 'magic' CRUD operations with Dapper:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    cn.Open();
    Person person = new Person { FirstName = "Foo", LastName = "Bar" };
    int id = cn.Insert(person);
    cn.Close();
}
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030285/dapper-rainbow-vs-dapper-contrib) thread for more...

Answer (score 13):

If you like the PetaPoco style the better, just go for it. Although Dapper is more famous, PetaPoco has the same performance, has the same concepts but it's a bit more flexible (IMO)

Comment: @Gaspa79 yes, you are right. Roughly enough for the vast majority of apps.

Comment: For MS Access/Jet database, PetaPoco is your saving grace.

Answer (score -1):

Developers use Drapper because of its performance. For many websites PetaPoco is good enough but if you want to extract all the server 'juice' use Drapper. In fact it is the ORM used by Stackoverflow. You can see all ORM performance comparison  [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#performance)

Comment: dude performance of Dapper and PetaPoco is basically identical 49ms v 52ms (v 631 for EF in the example).