# Is there a way to map properties to column names using some .Insert extension method for Dapper?

Tags: dapper, dapper-extensions, dapper-contrib, dapper-fastcrud

I have the following challenge with this class:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Property Id As Integer
    Property LastName as String
End Class
```

The corresponding data table in the database has as fields:
 `Id (int, not null)`
 `Last-Name (nvarchar(80),null)`

So I need to map `MyClass.LastName` to `MyClasses.Last-Name` and have a hell of a time...

When I write a custom Insert query it all works, but I would like to use the .Insert statement of one of the Dapper extensions packages.

I tried Dapper.Contrib, but this ignores mappings that I create using Dapper.FluentMap or using the built in method of Dapper itself using `Dapper.SetTypeMap`.

I tried Dapper.FastCrud, but I was unable to figure out how to configure mappings for it, though this API seems promising.

Anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, basically the problem here is that the property name and column name is different.

**With [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)**, you can handle this by providing alias for column name in SQL query. I guess you have already tried this as you said "*I write a custom Insert query*" in your question. Other multiple ways to map column names with properties are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8902674/5779732).

**With [DapperExtensions](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions)**, you can [map](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/Customized-mapping-for-a-class) the different column names with their respective properties something like below:

```
public sealed class MyClassMapper : ClassMapper<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMapper()
    {
        Table("MyTable");
        Map(x => x.Id).Key(KeyType.WhatYouWant);
        Map(x => x.LastName).Column("Last-Name");
        AutoMap();
    }
}
```

<sub>Code sample is with C#. You have to translate it to VB.NET.</sub>

**With [Dapper.Contrib](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib#special-attributes)**, you can decorate the class with `[Table]` attribute to map the table name. Alternatively, you can use [`SqlMapperExtensions.TableNameMapper`](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs) to map the tables. Please refer to [this](https://medium.com/@marco_be/dapper-contrib-custom-table-names-without-attribute-651746a8428b) blog post or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27341079/5779732) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8233314/5779732) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32204808/5779732) SO posts for more details.
Apparently, there is [no way](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/722) to [map](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/978) the column name. <strike>This feature is planned for next major (2.x) version.</strike> Version [2.x is released](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.Contrib/); but the [issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/722) is still open. Looking at [the release notes](https://stackexchange.github.io/Dapper/), feature is not yet added.

**With [Dapper.FastCrud](https://github.com/MoonStorm/Dapper.FastCRUD)**, there are [multiple ways](https://github.com/MoonStorm/Dapper.FastCRUD/wiki/Entity-registration#registration-via-attributes) for [mapping](https://github.com/MoonStorm/Dapper.FastCRUD/wiki/Multiple-mappings). You can decorate the property with `[Column]` attribute.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.Contrib/ shows version 2.0.78, Does it allow mapping column names? Is it possible for you to update answer? I can see https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/722 is still open.