# How do I use Dapper.Contrib with FluentMap to update an entity with an identity column?

Tags: dapper, dapper-contrib, dapper-fluentmap

I have a class called `Business`, which has a property `Id` that is a identity field in MS SQL Server database. When I do an `INSERT`, it works properly. If I do the following:

```
_db.Update(business);
```

I get an error:

> invalid column name 'id" the column in the DB is BusinessId

I have mapped it to `Id` as below:

```
public class BusinessMap : EntityMap<Business>
    {
        public BusinessMap()
        {
            Map(x => x.Id).ToColumn("BusinessId");                
        }
    }
```

Now keep in mind my `INSERT` works. I tried adding the `Key` attribute to the class

```
[Table("Business")]
    public class Business {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        .....
    }
```

My work around (which I hate, but is better than nothing):
I decided to just call a SP to do this, which sort of sucks because I was hoping dapper could handle this.

```
_db.Query("BusinessUpdate",
                param: new { businessId = business.Id, business.Name, business.LocatorUrl, business.Website }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

I don't know why we are forced to conclude that every identity column in our database is named "ID", that is ludicrous in my opinion, and I don't think I need to justify my schema design, it should let me change it. Now anytime a field is added, I have to change the SP and the code to call the SP, I will use this until I found the real answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are using [Dapper.FluentMap](https://github.com/henkmollema/Dapper-FluentMap). This tool works as mapper for Dapper; NOT for Dapper Contrib.
So while generating the query, Contrib do not know `BusinessId` column is mapped with `Id` property. It assumes that for `Id` property, there exist an `Id` column. The `INSERT` is working because your primary key is automatically being generated by RDBMS you are using.
To know more about mapping column/table names to properties/classes, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407241/is-there-a-way-to-map-properties-to-column-names-using-some-insert-extension-me) question.

If you are trying to update/change the ID using Dapper Contrib, then it is not supported. This is because ORMs like Dapper Contrib use ID for uniquely identifying the record while generating queries.
So when you call `_db.Update(business);` method, Dapper Contrib generate the query something like `UPDATE <table name> SET <column list except ID, with new values> WHERE <ID column> = ?`. As you can see, the `ID` is being used to uniquely identify the record to be updated while generating `UPDATE` query.
Unfortunately, I could not find reference for this. The [GitHub help](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions#simple-update-operation) also does not explicitly mention it.

The alternative is to bypass the Dapper Contrib and use Dapper's `Execute` method directly by writing query by hand. I am not sure but Dapper.FluentMap also have CRUD query generator named [Dommel](https://github.com/henkmollema/Dommel); you may try [one-to-one](https://github.com/henkmollema/Dommel#one-to-one-relations) mapping that it support.

<sub>Although you are using Dapper Contrib, most part of this answer is also applicable to Dapper Extensions or some other query generators associated with Dapper.</sub>

Comment: The link you sent me about mapping columns might point me in the right direction. I thank you sir!

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction to get it working, see my answer below

Comment: This answer got me to where I needed to be, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it to work. My first problem was there are several packages that add CRUD methods (Update). My code was calling Dapper.Contrib.Update and I wanted to call Update from DommelMapper.Update once I got my imports to use the correct Nuget Package.. I made progress.. Here is what worked for me

```
  public class BusinessMap :   DommelEntityMap<Business>
    {
        public BusinessMap()
        {
            ToTable("Business");
            Map(x => x.Id).ToColumn("BusinessId").IsKey().IsIdentity();
        }
    }


FluentMapper.Initialize(config =>
            {
                config.AddMap(new BusinessMap());
                config.ForDommel();
            });

public void UpdateBusiness(Business business)
        {
            using TransactionScope t = new TransactionScope();
            _db.Update(business);
            t.Complete();
        }
```

The issues is I was calling the wrong Update Extension (contrib) and not calling the Dommel Update Extension, which did not recognize my mappings

I've installed Dommel 2.3.2, Dapper.Contrib 2.0.78, Dapper.FluentMap.Dommel 2.0.0